# Cannot add new alignment constraints auto layout Xcode 6

Tags: uiscrollview, xcode6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Why I cannot add new alignment constraints on my scroll view ?

[image: alignement]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In order to add alignment constraints, you must select two or more items before pressing the *Align* button.  This is how *Interface Builder* knows which two objects to align.  You can select the items by dragging a box around them, or you can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the items.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very useful!

Answer (score 12):

If you are aligning to centre horizontally/vertically (which doesn't require a second view for reference) and still get this issue, then go to the size inspector (ruler icon in the top right navbar) and change the layout dropdown to **Automatic**.

This should then enable values and the button in the alignment constraints dialog.

Comment: You are the GOAT.